# Допустимо ли такое выделение вставной конструкции?

Tags: пунктуация, вставная-конструкция

Задавая предыдущий вопрос, заметил, что многие против такого сочетания знаков, выделяющего вставную конструкцию. А я его часто использую...

*Добравшись до вершины, узнал, что это не просто смотровая площадка, — большой балкон над пропастью, — какой я ее представлял, а начало длинного пешеходного маршрута.*

Comment: Любую вставную конструкцию можно выделить, к примеру, скобками. Но я чаще использую  два тире с двумя запятыми. Некоторые считают такой вариант устаревшим. Вопрос был об этом. Вот еще пример...   Условно определенный мной городской центр, – он же набережная, – представлял собой улицу, освещенную фонарями.

Answer (score 1):

Вставные конструкции сами по себе могут выделяться **только скобками или тире**. Такова пунктуационная норма.

В тексте вставной конструкции при этом сохраняются все необходимые для нее знаки (запятая, восклицательный и вопросительный знаки, многоточие, двоеточие). Например: *Оказалось, что в ближних к Градову деревнях **‒ не говоря про дальние, что в лесистой стороне, ‒** до сей поры весной в новолунье и в первый гром купались в реках и озерах*. Здесь запятая перед тире завершает оборот *что в лесистой стороне*, а не является частью сочетания запятой с тире. То есть запятая перед тире при вставках может появляться, только если эта запятая  выполняет другие функции, не связанные с обособлением вставной конструкции.

Comment: Оказалось, что в ближних к Градову деревнях,‒ не говоря про дальние, что в лесистой стороне, ‒ до сей поры весной в новолунье и в первый гром купались в реках и озерах. А я бы так написал. Это что, ошибка?@Aer

Comment: @Виктор да, запятая перед первым тире лишняя.

Comment: @Виктор И я полностью согласен с модератором.

Answer (score 1):

А где Вы видите **вставную конструкцию**?  Вставная конструкция - **предложение**, содержащее добавочные замечания, попутные указания, разъясняющие предложение в целом или отдельные слова, которые часто резко выпадают из синтаксической структуры целого.Было бы вставной конструкцией, если бы было так:...– *это был большой балкон над пропастью,* –... И тогда скобки были бы здесь более уместны.
В том виде, каков есть, это словосочетание, не предложение, оно поясняет слово "площадка". Можно назвать **приложением** или **пояснительным оборотом**, соответственно и пунктуация меняется. По крайней мере, первое сочетание запятой и тире объяснить  сложно.

Добравшись до вершины, узнал, что это не просто смотровая площадка – большой балкон над пропастью,  какой я ее представлял, а начало длинного пешеходного маршрута.

Придаточное определительное стоит после слова "пропасть" и путает смысл, заставляя относить к нему придаточное.Это грамматическая ошибка, которая делает всю конструкцию тяжеловесной. Избежать ошибки можно, действительно, с помощью вставной конструкции:

Добравшись до вершины, узнал, что это не просто смотровая площадка (она  была в виде большого балкона над пропастью),  какой я ее представлял, а начало длинного пешеходного маршрута.

А ещё лучше:Добравшись до вершины, узнал, что это не просто смотровая площадка ,  какой я ее представлял (она  была в виде большого балкона над пропастью), а начало длинного пешеходного маршрута.

Comment: Добравшись до вершины, узнал, что это не просто смотровая площадка , какой я ее представлял (по идее, она была бы в виде большого балкона над пропастью), а начало длинного пешеходного маршрута. Тогда так, иначе весь смысл "перевернулся". Только зачем это изменение первоначального варианта?@Людмила

Comment: Чтобы убрать соседство"пропастью,какой я её представлял" - это ошибка конструкции СПП

Answer (score 1):

Тут, явно, автор сам запутался "кто на ком стоял". Скорее всего, он имел ввиду, что представлял себе смотровую площадку в виде большого балкона над пропастью. Потом, "добравшись до вершины", он понял, "что  это не просто смотровая площадка, а начало длинного пешеходного маршрута". В итоге имеем следующее.
Добравшись до вершины, узнал, что это не просто смотровая площадка – большой балкон над пропастью, какой я ее представлял, – а начало длинного пешеходного маршрута.Все правила соблюдены и смысл понятен. :-)

Comment: **Скорее всего, он имел ввиду, что представлял себе смотровую площадку в виде большого балкона над пропастью.** Да, так и было. Со стороны - виднее: автор (в смысле я) представляет все, как видел, а описать иногда может нечто, непонятное остальным. Поправил в соответствие с предложенным образцом.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Рад был помочь. Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Добравшись до вершины, узнал, **что это не просто смотровая площадка**, – большой балкон над пропастью, – **какой я ее представлял**, а начало длинного пешеходный маршрута.

**Вставка** выделена с помощью двух тире, первая запятая закрывает первое придаточное, а вторая запятая  открывает второе придаточное.

**По поводу вставки**

Со вставкой здесь всё в порядке, вставные конструкции – это  авторское решение, и **содержание их может быть самым разнообразным**. В данном случае вставкой является небольшое **лирическое отступление**, в котором автор сравнивает смотровую площадку с балконом. Отличительной особенностью вставных конструкций является только  **особая интонация** (выделение паузами и общее понижение тона речи), они как бы интонационно выпадают из общего текста.

Answer (score 0):

Только перед вторым тире:

*Добравшись до вершины, узнал, что это не просто смотровая площадка – большой балкон над пропастью, – какой я ее представлял, а начало длинного пешеходного маршрута*.

**Пояснение**

Перед первым тире запятая не нужна, поскольку вставка относится **к придаточному**, а точнее к словам *смотровая площадка*, которые находятся внутри придаточного. Следовательно, вставка входит в придаточное и нет никаких оснований (будь то деепричастный оборот, обособленное обстоятельство — в общем, всë то, что внутри придаточного, перед вставкой, обособленное и не относящееся к вставке) ставить запятую.

Запятая перед вторым тире ставится перед придаточным определительным.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, однако.  Здесь УТОЧНЕНИЕ, зависимый оборот ("вложенная" конструкция),  и первая запятая закрывает его.  Недавно разбирали-таки: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475875/Запятая-перед-обоими-тире

Answer (score 0):

**Любопытная тема 2016 года.** Давно это было! Много ответов, разные мнения, да и участники форума с хорошим практическим опытом (не считая меня, так как это мой первый год работы). **Трудный вопрос?** Мне думается, все дело в том, что **неудачно** выбрана вставка.

**Основное** содержание предложения: *Добравшись до вершины, узнал, что это **не просто смотровая площадка, а начало** длинного пешеходного маршрута.*  Противопоставление нужно четко обозначить, поэтому все остальное — это вставка.

**МОЙ ВАРИАНТ 2023 года:**

*Добравшись до вершины, узнал, что это не просто смотровая площАдка, — **большой балкон над пропастью, КАК я ее представлял,** —  а начАло длинного пешеходного маршрута.*

Союз ***КАК!***  **Замена!**

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

1. Почему участник @Людмила **сомневается**, что это вставка? Вероятно, дело в том, что вставка может просто **вписаться** в предложение как обособленное **приложение** (оно не выпадает из его структуры, как обычная вставка), например:

*Добравшись до вершины, узнал, что это не просто смотровая площадка, **(ТО ЕСТЬ) большой балкон над пропастью, как я ее представлял,** а начало длинного пешеходного маршрута.*

Это не мешает использовать **вставочное оформление**, но надо учитывать, что **первую запятую** придется поставить, так как она **структурная.**  Вставка является **уточняющей** по отношению к существительному "площадка".

2. **Но так ли это?** Такие вставки встречаются **не часто**, но что-то похожее мы разбирали недавно: *Называли фамилии мужей и братьев, – **живы ли, здоровы ли они?** – как будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих, дравшихся на всех фронтах* (А. Т.).

Первая запятая здесь **стоит**.  **[§ 97](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128)**

3. В любом случае вставка смотрится как **симметричная**, даже интонационно отнести ее к первой части затруднительно. Дело в том, что надо выделить ударением однородные члены: ***не площАдка, а начАло.***
4. **Еще одно NEW!**

Вставка — это фактически **обособленное приложение?** Прекрасно! Обособить эту сложную конструкцию только тире **недостаточно,** так как здесь нужен более **сильный знак.** Тогда выбираем **единый знак**, то есть запятую и тире. Получаем **два тире и две запятые**, что и требовалось доказать.

5. Еще возможно **такое понимание.** Собственно говоря, основное предложение выглядит так:

...это не просто смотровая площадка, — **большой балкон над пропастью, как я ее представлял**, — а начало длинного пешеходного маршрута.

Первая запятая структурная, обозначает **обособленное приложение**, а вторая запятая (тоже структурная) стоит в простом предложении **перед союзом А**

Comment: «_...это не просто смотровая площадка, — **большой балкон над пропастью, какой я ее представлял**, — а…_» ❓=== Наверное, правильнее будет применительно к **балкону** сказать не _**какой я ее представлял**_, а _**каким я ее** представлял_? Может, я и ошибаюсь…

Comment: Он же изначально представлял площадку  в виде балкона, поэтому я убрала согласование с чем-либо, а местоимение "её" оставила для площадки. Я ее (площадку) представлял КАК большой балкон.