# Запятая перед обоими тире

Tags: запятые, тире, придаточное-предложение, вставная-конструкция, вводное-слово

`Разумеется, — и это очевидно, — чтобы добиться успеха, нужно много работать.`

Как думаете, верно ли расставлены запятые? По [«Розенталю» (пункт 4 — 2, 3)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123) выходит так.

Запятую перед первым тире требует структура первой части предложения, а именно **вводное слово**; а запятую перед вторым тире требует структура второй части — **слово *чтобы***.

По такой логике запятые нужны с обоих сторон. А вы как думаете, совы?

Comment: Почему повтор вопроса  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475854/Почему-запятая-перед-вставкой-а-не-после

Comment: Нет, это уже другое.

Comment: Тогда надо  как-то объединить тему. Вопросов  очень много, сложно ориентироваться.  Да и названия вопросов должны отражать их суть. Иначе они похожи как близнецы.  В этом есть и ваша заинтересованность, будет больше просмотров.

Comment: Максим, мне нравится этот вопрос, определенные мысли есть.. Голос от меня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Верен единственный вариант:

***Разумеется, — и это очевидно — чтобы добиться успеха, нужно много работать***.

Вставка относится к следующей части, поэтому запятой их не отделяем и переносим еë со второго тире на первое. Запятая перед первым тире стоит на двух основаниях:

1. Обособляет ваодное слово, которое к вставке не относится;
2. Ставится между частями СПП.

**[«Грамота.ру»](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=311507)**:

> Здравствуйте, уважаемые специалисты! Нужна ли запятая перед вторым тире вставки? «Разумеется, — и это очевидно(,)— чтобы добиться успеха, нужно много работать». Ваш ответ мне важен очень. Прям сильно важен! Надеюсь получить как можно быстрее. Спасибо заранее!
>
> ---
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> ---
>
> Для этой запятой нет оснований. Вводное слово *разумеется* отделено от остального высказывания первой запятой, вставная конструкция *и это очевидно* выделена с помощью парного тире; далее, с союза *чтобы*, начинается первая предикативная часть сложноподчиненного предложения.

Comment: Чудненько! Чем отличается от моего ответа? Единым знаком? А я по слуху пишу, пауза там больше.  А по Грамоте как читать надо? Последовательно? Сначала первое вводное, потом вставку, потом основное предложение. Три части для такого маленького предложения?  Верен единственный вариант?  Ну что ж, для школьников сойдет, отчитаться можно.  А вы часто на Грамоту заглядываете, они всегда пишут единственно верные ответы? Тогда зачем на форуме спрашивать? Как-то и отвечать вам расхотелось.

Comment: @Sharon Были ответы, которые я верными не считал. КАЖДЫЙ имеет СВОЮ точку зрения, — это вам не изменить. В конечном счéте решил вопрос задать туда.

Comment: Мне не очень нравится категоричность вашего высказывания. Сказали бы так:  Грамота.ру считает верным такой ответ, и я с ним согласен. Но вы принимаете сами себя по указанию Грамоты.  А они ссылок на правило не дают, их рассуждение о структуре весьма свободное. Но каждый из нас свободен в своих действиях)  И отсюда все выводы.

Comment: И еще раз о структуре предложения. Деление на три части!  Конечно, вставка не входит в состав предложения и как бы не считается, А вот в состав устной речи она входит. И как читать? Такое предложение  пользователи языка в любом случае разделят пополам, а не на три части, Вот я смотрю на предложение и вижу СИЛЬНЫЙ знак слева. Там и сделаю паузу, а вставка пойдет направо. Но такие мелочи Грамота не учитывает.

Answer (score 0):

1. Исходное предложение:

***Разумеется, чтобы** добиться успеха, нужно много работать.*

2. Вставка, запятая **перенесенная**:

*Разумеется **— и это очевидно, —** чтобы добиться успеха, нужно много работать.*

Comment: Подождите... Вы пишете, конструкция смещается влево и вводые дополняют друг друга. Тогда почему вы их запятой разделили, если они дополнены и конструкция «смещена влево»? Да и к тому же, как она может относиться к левой части, если очевидно, что относится к правой?

Comment: Максим, ждать не буду)) Зачем так быстро принимаете?  Я рассчитывала на долгое обсуждение))  Отзовите приемку.  Это же NEW, новый подход.  Может, и неверный.

Comment: То есть это не факт, а просто рассуждения?))

Comment: Это мой новый прием решения подобных задач. Прошу участников форума дать оценку)

Comment: А что насчет самого верхнего вопроса, под вашим ответом?

Comment: Не поняла. Постановка знаков в этих двух предложениях одинаковая. Ситуация одна и та же. Предложение надо разделить на вводную и основную часть, а при симметрии у нас три части.

Comment: Хорошо. А принятие пока отозвать, да? Чтобы остальные участники оценили.

Comment: Да, отзовите. Был же разговор о том, что вообще не надо спешить с приемкой. Всем!  А то бывает так: не все участники вопрос прочитали, а его уже приняли.

Comment: Меня всегда расстраивала ФОРМАЛЬНОСТЬ  этого правила, хотелось увидеть в нем какой-то смысл. Симметричные/несимметричные запятые  должны быть знаком для понимания семантики и структуры предложения.

Comment: @Sharon, какие новые подходы могут быть в лингвистике, тем более, в пунктуации? Ну вы же знаете это как никто лучше. Прежде, чем что-то решать, принимать, вопрос будет обсуждать научная комиссия. В нашем случае обсуждать-то и нечего. В правилах этот пункт освящён.

Comment: Святой пункт? А вы вообще-то о чем? Я о том, как нам лучше изучить Розенталя. Правила никто не меняет, ответы должны совпадать. Методик много, их освящать не надо.  Или вот ситуация. Встретился пример, который не разобран у Розенталя. Как решать? И удивительно, что вы не не все понимаете. Прочитайте еще раз вступление Розенталя к правилам, где говорится о гибкости пунктуации. Это школьники должны писать по пунктам, а есть еще литература.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант:

*Разумеется, — ***и это очевидно***, — чтобы добиться успеха, нужно много работать.*

**Пояснение**

Первая запятая **структурная,** вместо второго тире **единый знак.** Вставка уточняет вводное слово.

Варианты **без вставки**:

*Разумеется, ***и это очевидно***, — чтобы добиться успеха, нужно много работать.*

*Разумеется, **и это очевидно**: чтобы добиться успеха, нужно много работать.*